# Playing sprite animation sequence slow on first loop

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, png, vuforia

I just made a png animation sequence that fires when the object is found but on the first loop it takes a lot to load, is there a way to load it faster?

The animation consist of 500 pngs loaded in a sprite the total size of all is about 180Mb, and the code that I am using is very simple:

DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs:

```
public SpriteRenderer sr;
public int i = 0;

void Update ()
{
   i++;
   i = (i > 100) ? 0 : i;
   sr.sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite> ("fractal/03_" + i.ToString ("D5"));
}
```

btw i'm a complete noob on unity programming so please forgive me if i'm missing something obvious, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are loading sprite every frame. It will effect performance. Do the loading **once** in the `Start` function and store the result in an array. You can then use that array in the `Update` function.

```
const int ANIM_SIZE = 500;
Sprite[] animSprites;
public SpriteRenderer sr;
public int i = 0;

void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ANIM_SIZE; i++)
    {
        animSprites[i] = Resources.Load<Sprite>("fractal/03_" + i.ToString("D5")) as Sprite;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    i++;
    i = (i > 100) ? 0 : i;
    sr.sprite = animSprites[i];
}
```

---

Since you are loading many files, you should use `Resources.LoadAsync` instead. That will let you load the data over frame and prevent any possible freezing when loading the sprites.

```
const int ANIM_SIZE = 500;
Sprite[] animSprites;
public SpriteRenderer sr;
public int i = 0;
bool isDoneLoading = false;

IEnumerable Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < ANIM_SIZE; i++)
    {
        ResourceRequest rs = Resources.LoadAsync<Sprite>("fractal/03_" + i.ToString("D5"));
        yield return rs;
        animSprites[i] = rs.asset as Sprite;
    }

    isDoneLoading = true;
}

void Update()
{
    if (isDoneLoading)
    {
        i++;
        i = (i > 100) ? 0 : i;
        sr.sprite = animSprites[i];
    }
}
```

---

Finally, don't use any of these solutions mentioned above. They are just there because that's what you asked for. Use the Unity's Animation/Animator's tool to do this. You can learn more about this [here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj8vN3JuNrTAhXJzIMKHXc_CPkQFggpMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Funity3d.com%2Flearn%2Ftutorials%2Fprojects%2F2d-roguelike-tutorial%2Fplayer-and-enemy-animations&usg=AFQjCNGxUxL0_yh37Uo3wf5b_23gIynpqw).

Comment: Thanks for your info.. there is a ton of things i didn't knew, i will learn the animation tool but in the meantime im doing your first example, i get this error: Assets/Sprite.cs(22,27): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `Sprite' to `UnityEngine.Sprite', do you know what can i be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have that error. Maybe you are using older version of Unity. Add `as Sprite` to the end of the load function. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help... i redid it using the animation tool and it worked perfectly...